# bind_param character type for checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, prepared-statement

Just wondering when using mysqli_stmt_bind_param for a checkbox value. Would the character type be integer 'i' for this? - as the checkbox sends off either a 1 or a 0. Asking just to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

1. data source has nothing to do with these matters, be it checkbox, csv file or a hardcoded value. Only destination matters.
2. So, it's *database field type* have to be your concern only.
3. Nevertheless, in most cases mysql can happily accept *strings* for all values, so, you can bother not with all these bindings but use s all the way.